# Find files older than x amount of time in specific directory with ignoring subdirectories

Tags: find, aix, timestamps

My setup is as following:

**folder structure**

```
dir
 |--correctfile1
 |--correctfile2
 |--correctfile3
 |--subdir1
   |--wrongfile1
   |--wrongfile2
   |--wrongfile3
 |--subdir2
 |--subdir3
```

I need to find out if there are files in `dir` that are older than 3 minutes. This means I should ignore folders `subdir1, subdir2 and subdir3` and only search in the main directory `dir`

I have following one-liner

```
find $dir -mmin +3 -type f
```

but this prints also the files from subdir1

Some extra info:

AIX 5.3

find command does not have `-maxdepth`, `-mindepth`, `-or`, `-not` or `-path` options

---

The manpage: http://textuploader.com/oe0r

Comment: +1 for "find command does not have -maxdepth, -not or -path options" info...

Comment: Why find does not have that options? can you [upload](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) the man page of that and post the link? may be it use another option for that.

Comment: @KasiyA: I added the manpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A portable way to prevent `find` from recursing is to execute the `-prune` action on directories other than the toplevel directory.

```
find "$dir" \! -name "$(basename -- "$dir")" -type d -prune -o -mmin +3 -type f -print
```

Comment: No filenames, just the name of $dir so in the above example: dir

Comment: @TimothyPersoon And if you add `-print` after `-type f`?

Comment: then it returns nothing

Comment: @TimothyPersoon Are there files in `dir` which match `-mmin +3`? Does your `find $dir -mmin +3 -type f` return files which are not in a subdirectory?

Comment: Yes, it returns /dir/file1, /dir/file2 and /dir/subdir/file1

Comment: @TimothyPersoon I have no good idea why that is but you may try these: `find $dir \( \! -name . -type d -prune \) -o \( -mmin +3 -type f -print \)` and `find $dir -type f -mmin +3 -print -o \! -name . -type d -prune`

Comment: I'd use `find $dir \( ! -name $(basename $dir) -type d -prune \) -o -mmin +3 -type f -print`

Comment: I find it strange that a `find` command that understands `-mmin` doesn't understand `-maxdepth`. On what system is this?

Comment: @Hauke: it returns nothing

Comment: OK, I'm stupid: `-name .` is the wrong test. I always use `find . ...`. Thus `$dir` is matched for `-prune` and the whole tree is ignored. It must be `\! -name "$dir"` as wurtel pointed out.

Comment: @wurtel: doesn't work. System is aix 5.3 and see my question for the manpage

Comment: @wurtel: I must have done something wrong because now it works! Thanx, now I need to get it into my script and that also gives an error but that's something else